# GitLab CI/Docker on Windows/node container - unknown network http

Tags: node.js, docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to run basic pipeline that should build my web-project using GitLab CI

My setup:

- GitLab CE 10.1.4 on Ubuntu 16.04
- GitLab Runner 10.1.0 on Windows 10 1703 with docker executor
- Docker 17.09.0-ce-win33 (13620) on same Windows machine

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: node:latest

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

build:
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build
```

And I get failed build with this output:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.1.0 (c1ecf97f)
    on ****** (9366a476)
Using Docker executor with image node:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:4d72396806765f67139745bb91135098acaf23ce7d627e41eb4da9c62e5d6729 for predefined container...
Pulling docker image node:latest ...
Using docker image node:latest ID=sha256:cf20b9ab2cbc1b6f76e820839ad5f296b4c9a9fd04f3e74651c16ed49943dbc4 for build container...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): dial http: unknown network http
```

I've thought that problem might happen because container can't access internet, but https://hub.docker.com/r/byrnedo/alpine-curl/ curl container got the data, so I think it's not the case.

UPD:
Problem occurs when GitLab runner try to attach to container.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in GitLab CI config (config.toml), docker host.

`host = "http://127.0.0.1:2375"` - wrong one

should be `host = "tcp://127.0.0.1:2375"`